# How to count the number of columns in the header of a csv file?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to count the number of header columns in a CSV file e.g.

A file called `test.csv`

```
a,b,c,d 
1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2
.......
n,n,n,n
```

should give me 4 columns. If I do:

```
awk -F, '{print NF}' ./test.csv
```

I will get 4 but n times i.e. I will get the number of columns for as many rows as there are and it is not really efficient. I tried this alternative form but doesn't work because it needs an input file:

```
awk -F, '{print NF}' `head -n 1 ./test.csv`
```

I could use this alternative but I find it ugly having to create a tmp file:

```
head -n 1 ./test.csv > tmp && awk -F, '{print NF}' tmp && rm tmp
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just print `NF` and exit.

```
awk -F, '{print NF; exit}' file.csv
```

It should be pointed out that this is **not** safe for arbitrary csv as csv can quote commas within elements and awk will not handle that correctly.

Comment: So simple… I like it!

Comment: hmm but this prints simply 1 and not the number of columns ... did you test it? I think maybe you are missing the `awk -F, ...` bit

Comment: @GiovanniAzua Indeed, I missed setting FS in that snippet. Fixing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that you have always the same number of columns, print `NF` only for the first line:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print NF}' ./test.csv
```

You could also use `head` without temporary files:

```
awk -F, '{print NF}' <(head -1 f)
head -1 f |awk -F, '{print NF}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use head for this.  Just flip what you have around, and pipe it to awk.

```
head -n 1 test.csv | awk -F, '{print NF}'
```